# ¿Extraer campos vacíos de una tabla consulta sql server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php5

Quiero extraer los valores de los campos fechaEntrada y fechaSalida aun cuando estos esten vacios y a la vez estos 2 campos sacan la diferencia y se muestra en el campo sumaHoras, de una tabla llamada tblAsistencia

Cabe señalar que estoy generando un reporte en excel y genera un ERROR: PHP Notice:  Undefined index cuando un registro no tiene datos en fechaEntrada,
sin embargo el reporte se va verificando continuamente y como tal en algún momento los campos fechaEntrada y fechaSalida ya tendrían los datos, por lo tanto el detalle seria corregir que aun cuando no existan datos en los campos fechaEntrada y fechaSalida aun asi se genere el reporte no importa que este arroje los valores de: 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 o sustituirlos por 00:00:00.000 simplemente 0 o Null.

Intente acoplarlo de esta manera, pero sin éxito alguno: 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada))
    ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida)

La funcion: consultarFecha() de esta manera:

```
public function consultarFecha($empno,$fechainicio)
{

$res = Array("idclave"=>"","fechaEntrada"=>"","fechaSalida"=>"");


$qry = "select 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida, 
            DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS sumaHoras 
        from tblasistencia where idclave = '".$empno."' and 
            fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 00:00:00', 103) and 
            CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 23:59:59',103)";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,$qry);

if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() . " qry " .$qry, true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

//  echo $row['fechaEntrada'].", ".$row['FechaSalida']."<br />";
    //$res["idclave"] =  $row['idclave'];
    $res["fechaEntrada"] = $row['fechaEntrada'];
    $res["fechaSalida"] = $row['fechaSalida'];
    $res["sumaHoras"] = $row['sumaHoras'];

}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

return  $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de utilizar:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada))
```

Usa `switch`.

Ejemplo:

```
CASE WHEN fechaEntrada IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), fechaEntrada, 108) END AS [fechaEntrada]
```

Answer (score 0):

si fecha entrada no tiene valores '' te dara error o 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 y si sacas la diferencia resta de fecha de dos variables seteada a esto sera 0 o Null o error.

o en su defecto lo que buscas es recibir una fecha:

o en su defecto según comentarios puedes:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000;
```

con esto alteras la tabla y le pones una fecha por defecto esto hara que todos los campos vacios o null se actualicen tomando este nuevo valor como por defecto y a la hora de llevarlo al excel ya tendras por defecto una fecha y evitaras el error.

Comment: Cabe señalar que estoy generando un reporte en excel y genera un ERROR: PHP Notice:  Undefined index cuando un registro no tiene datos en fechaEntrada,
sin embargo el reporte se va verificando continuamente y como tal en algun momento los campos fechaEntrada y fechaSalida ya tendrían los datos, por lo tanto el detalle seria corregir que aun cuando no existan datos en los campos fechaEntrada y fechaSalida aun asi se genere el reporte no importa que este arroje los valores de: 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 o sustituirlos por 00:00:00.000 o simplemente 0 o Null.

Comment: y por que no cambias la columna a un defaul Null y en la exportación si el campo es null los remplace por 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: o en su defecto según comentarios puedes:

ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000;